# How to deal with GSON with nested abstract classes?

Tags: java, gson, abstract-class

i read a lot about the use of `TypeAdapter` and `JsonSerializer/Deserializer` to deal with abstract class, my problem is in case of nested abstract class.
Let say this class:

```
abstract class A {
  String content;
}

abstract class G {
  String otherContent;
}

class B extends A {
  G g;
}

class C extends A {
  String someThing;
}

class H extends G {
  Integer num;
}
```

I already coded a `JsonSerializer/Deserializer` class for each abstract class `A` and `G`.
I know I can use the chaining on: `gsonbuilder.registerTypeAdapter(A_Adapter).registerTypeAdapter(G_Adapter)`, but i need to use something more like the `TypeAdapterFactory` to identify witch adapter to use (to specify the adapter class corresponding to the abstract class i used a `java annotaion/reflection`).
I also seen the `TypeAdapter` class but it too complex to implement due to the missing of the `context` element present in the `JsonSerializer/Deserializer`.

Any idea how to do it?

Comment: How about having one class that combines all the fields and just let Gson set them to null (or preferably Optional in Java 8) when they're missing? At least for deserialize.... Otherwise, I think you should show your JSON

Comment: Thanks for the response, i cant do that, indeed my class system is much more complicate and i need the inheritence/abstractisation fonctionality

Comment: @RCMSAS do you want to use same serializer and desrializer for every subtype of `A` class(`A`+`B`+`C`)? And another TypeAdapter for  `G` + `H`?

Comment: @varren you're right that's exactly what i need, indeed i just have one `serialiser/deserializer` per abstract class and this `serialiser/deserializer` class is specified in a java annotation for each abstract class respectively

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use same serializer and desrializer for every subtype of `A`class(`A`+`B`+`C`) you can use `registerTypeHierarchyAdapter(A.class, new A_Adapter())`
From [documentation](https://google.github.io/gson/apidocs/com/google/gson/GsonBuilder.html#registerTypeHierarchyAdapter-java.lang.Class-java.lang.Object-):

> Configures Gson for custom serialization or deserialization for an
>   inheritance type hierarchy. This method combines the registration of a
>   TypeAdapter, JsonSerializer and a JsonDeserializer. If a type adapter
>   was previously registered for the specified type hierarchy, it is
>   overridden. If a type adapter is registered for a specific type in the
>   type hierarchy, it will be invoked instead of the one registered for
>   the type hierarchy.

Comment: That's answer only a half of my question, now i want to insert them in a `typeadapterfactory`. Actualy I just want to automate the system, that all time i call `gson.fromJson/toJson` it search for each class used in the object (for any deep level in the object), wich of this one has my `@classSerializer java annotation` containing the right `serialiser/deserializer` to use. And if it has it use this class to serialize/deserialize this part of the object.
I hope i explained my self well :)